# E[XY] using Bivariate Normal Distribution.

Tags: probability

Ultimately, I would like to calculate $Cov(X,Y)$ assuming X and Y are jointly normal.$$$$$$Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$$I know how to calculate $E[X]E[Y]$, but am stuck when attempting to calculate $E[XY]$.

How can the following double integral be calculated, assuming all necessary parameters are given?

$$E[XY]=∫_{-∞}^∞ ∫_{-∞}^∞\frac{xy}{2σ_x σ_y \sqrt{1-ρ^2}} exp(\frac{-1}{2(1-ρ^2)}  (\frac{(x-μ_x)}{σ_x})^2+(\frac{(y-μ_y)}{σ_y})^2-\frac{2ρ(x-μ_x )(y-μ_y )}{(σ_x σ_y ))}) dxdy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the correlation is $\rho$, the covariance is $\rho \sigma_x \sigma_y$.
But if you want to do it the hard way, complete the square in $\exp(\ldots)$ for $y$ and use $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty y \exp(-A(y-c)^2) \; dy = c \sqrt{\pi/A}\ \text{for } A > 0$$
then do similarly for $x$.